# Changing background image does not change the image on browser

Tags: html, css

Here is a `<div>` which has background image like

```
style {
    .bg { background-image:url("../images.png");
          background-position:-5px -100px;
    }
}

...

<div class="bg"></div>
```

and I change the **image file with same name**. For example, I change the color of image file and save with same name.
But it does not change the image on browser. I changed the color of image from red to blue. But it is still red.
How can I refresh the background image? Thanks

Comment: Clear browser cookies and try if you are using any server like http-server restart your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift+F5 - refresh without cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try open that in incognito window/private window to check CSS or images related changes, as it add it to cache of the browser.

Or you can simply try it by CTRL + R.

Answer (score 1):

For mac you can try with **cmd+shift+r**